# Difference between [ ] and Expression API?

Tags: python, python-polars

What is the difference between using square brackets `[ ]` and using [**Expression APIs**](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/index.html) like `select`, `filter`, etc. when trying to access data from a polars Dataframe? Which one to use when?

a polars dataframe

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c"],
        "b": [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1],
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, it is advised to use the polars expression API as most of the methods are part of polars [*lazy* API](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/lazy/). The API defers the evaluation of many operations, such as selection, filtering, and mutation, until the result is actually needed. This allows for the [query optimizations](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/lazy/optimizations/) that makes polars as efficient as it is.

In contrast, accessing columns using square bracket notation only work in eager-mode.

### Example.

As an concrete example, consider reading the first element of a rather large .csv file (~700mb). We start by creating the .csv file and write it to disk.

```py
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame({"col": [0] * 100_000_000}).write_csv("df.csv")
```

**Using square bracket notation (`[`).**

As square bracket notation does not work on `LazyFrames`, we'll need to use `pl.read_parquet` to read the file into a `DataFrame` object.

```
pl.read_csv("df.csv")["col"][0]
```

On my machine, this takes roughly 200ms.

**Using polars lazy API.**

The same can be achieved using polars lazy API (`pl.scan_csv`, `select`, `first`, `item`).

```
pl.scan_csv("df.csv").select("col").first().collect().item()
```

The delay of the evaluation allows polars to avoid reading in the entire file and the execution only takes 300μs on my machine, i.e. *we obtained a ~650x speed-up by using polars' lazy API.*

Of course, one could argue that much of the time here is saved by avoiding to read the entire .csv file instead of by using `select` over `[`. However, note that this is still *due to the benefits of the lazy API*.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different things.

`[]` is a list literal. This is bult into python. In your example code, you are creating lists to build a polars dataframe.

On the other hand, `select()`, `filter()` etc. are functions you can use on a data frame to manipulate it. These are all part of the polars package and are not available in vanilla python.

Comment: I believe they're talking about `df[...]` notation i.e. `df.__getitem__()` / `df.__setitem__()`

Comment: @jqurious Oh, that makes sense. I was basing my answer from their example code only.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between using square brackets `[]` and the Expression API (such as `select`, `filter`) in Polars is in functionality and performance optimisation.

1. Use `square brackets []` for simple, straightforward tasks like selecting a `column` or filtering `rows` based on a direct condition.
2. Use Expression API when dealing with more complex transformations, aggregations, or when performance optimisation is more important.

Here is a basic example with output based on your `dataframe`:

#### Using `[]`

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c"],
    "b": [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1],
})

simple_selection = df["a"]
print(simple_selection)
```

**[image: Output]**:

#### Using `Expression API`

```
complex_operation = df.filter(pl.col("b") > 1).select([
    pl.col("a"),
    (pl.col("b") * 2).alias("double_b")
])

print(complex_operation)
```

**Output:**

[image]